# Magento - Add zip code / postcode to the order grid in Magento 1.6.2

Tags: magento, select, collections, grid

I am trying to get the order grid to display the postcode/ zip code of the of the customer.

I am trying to join the sales_flat_order_address alias with the collection but to no success.

```
protected function _prepareCollection() {
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
   $collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order_address', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_address.parent_id',array('postcode'));
  //var_dump($collection);
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

Can any one please help me figure out a solution for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before return parent::_prepareCollection(); You should create a join:

```
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('billing'=>'sales_flat_order_address'),
    'main_table.entity_id = billing.parent_id AND billing.address_type="billing"',array('billing.postcode AS bp'));
```

If you want the shipping postcode instead, use:

```
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('shipping'=>'sales_flat_order_address'),
    'main_table.entity_id = shipping.parent_id AND shipping.address_type="shipping"',array('shipping.postcode AS sp'));
```

And in the method _prepareColumns paste:

```
$this->addColumn('bp', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Billing Postcode'),
        'index' => 'bp',
        'width' => '60px',
        'filter_index'  => 'billing.postcode'
    ));
```

That worked for me in a recent project.